# Generator expressions in Julia

Tags: julia

I tried to implement a Generator expressions in Julia, but I run in an error which I do not know how to fix.

```
julia> using JSON

julia> path = "test.txt"

julia> JSON.parse(readline(open(path)))
Dict{String,Any} with 16 entries:
  "nk" => 1
  "cy" => "Danvers"
  "c"  => "US"
  "hh" => "1.usa.gov"
  "r"  => "http://www.facebook.com/l/7AQEFzjSi/1.usa.gov/wfLQtf"
  "a"  => "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.11 (KHTML, like …
  "h"  => "wfLQtf"
  "t"  => 1331923247
  "g"  => "A6qOVH"
  "tz" => "America/New_York"
  "ll" => {42.576698,-70.954903}
  "l"  => "orofrog"
  "hc" => 1331822918
  "gr" => "MA"
  "u"  => "http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22415991"
  "al" => "en-US,en;q=0.8"

julia> record = [JSON.parse(line) for line in eachline(open(path))]
ERROR: no method length(EachLine)
in anonymous at no file
```

Comment: I'm using julia version 0.3.0-prerelease+4029

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use list comprehensions with objects that have lengths that aren't known a priori. I think you need a `while` loop here.

I'm also not sure that you can use JSON parsing with line-oriented input, since JSON boundaries might occur across line boundaries.

Comment: In my case all json entries in the file are in one line. Is this a good solution: using JSON

records = Dict{String,Any}[]
open(path,"r") do f
    for line in eachline(f)
        push!(records, JSON.parse(line))
    end
end
records [1]

Answer (score 1):

If the file is not too big, you can use `readlines` instead of `eachline` because it returns an array, instead of a iterator (and arrays have a length method and can be used in comprehensions).

My favorite is the one you described in the comment:

```
using JSON
records = Dict{String,Any}[]
open(path,"r") do f
    for line in eachline(f)
        push!(records, JSON.parse(line))
    end
end
```